# Subversion with CruiseControl triggers: Cannot negotiate authentication mechanism

Tags: svn, authentication, tortoisesvn, cruisecontrol.net

I've got a cruisecontrol config file set up to poll the SVN server and in theory update if there are recent modifications.  However whenever the trigger is hit, it fails with:

```
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: Source control operation failed: svn: Cannot negotiate authentication mechanism
. Process command: C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin\svn.exe update C:\Source\Wholesale\XXXX.SWControl.TestingFramework\ --username mmayo --password ******** --no-auth-cache --non-interactive
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ProcessSourceControl.Execute(ProcessInfo processInfo)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Svn.UpdateSource(IIntegrationResult result)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Svn.GetSource(IIntegrationResult result)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Build(IIntegrationResult result)
   at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest request)
```

The relevant lines in my config are:

```
<sourcecontrol type="svn">
        <trunkUrl>http://app7002-svn.oy.gb.sportingindex.com/CoreAPI/trunk/Wholesale/XXXX.EventControl.TestingFramework</trunkUrl>
        <executable>C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin\svn.exe</executable>
        <workingDirectory>C:\Source\Wholesale\SPIN.SWControl.TestingFramework\
        </workingDirectory>
        <username>mmayo</username>
        <password>********</password>
      </sourcecontrol>
      <triggers>
        <intervalTrigger name="Subversion" seconds="60" />
      </triggers>
```

There are various issues on the net talking about how it could be SSH key pair problems, but given the simple setup, the lack of SSH and all that, I'm sure it's just something simple I'm missing.

Alternatively, if you've got a working TortoiseSVN CC.Net script, I'd love to see it ;)

Comment: Can you post your `svnserver.conf` file (the subversion config file) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your build server, have you tried to manually pull down the code using those credentials, or with your own credentials?  If neither work, the svn server may be blocking the build server.

Another potential - have you tried setting the trunk url to "svn://..." instead of "http://..."?  Depending on how your svn server is set up, that may be an easier way of accessing the projects.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with Tortoise SVN 1.7 BETA 64bit under Windows 64bit, with and without CruiseControl.Net.

The solution was to add a registry key on the client PC in

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Carnegie Mellon\Project Cyrus\SASL Library

(I had to create this "path")

with the label:

SearchPath

which contains the string:

C:\path\to\svn\binary\with\sassl\support\bin

which was  ..."\TortoiseSVN\bin" for me

Found in:

http://wiki.nullstack.net/SVN_cannot_negotiate_authentication_mechanism